# Android Printooth TextPrintable alignment doesn't work

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am trying to print invoice info using Printooth Library, but the problem is that it's not printing as expected. It seems that something is wrong with alignment and I can't find a reason why. This is code which I used to create text I want to print out

```
fun getPrintables(printData: PrintData) = ArrayList<Printable>().apply {

    add(RawPrintable.Builder(byteArrayOf(27, 100, 4)).build())

    add(
        TextPrintable.Builder()
            .setText( printData.title)
            .setLineSpacing(DefaultPrinter.LINE_SPACING_60)
            .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALIGNMENT_CENTER)
            .setFontSize(DefaultPrinter.FONT_SIZE_LARGE)
            .setEmphasizedMode(DefaultPrinter.EMPHASIZED_MODE_BOLD)
            .setUnderlined(DefaultPrinter.UNDERLINED_MODE_OFF)
            .setNewLinesAfter(1)
            .build()
    )

    add(
        TextPrintable.Builder()
            .setText("Amount:  0.002")
            .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
            .setCharacterCode(DefaultPrinter.CHARCODE_PC437)
            .build()
    )

    add(
        TextPrintable.Builder()
            .setText("POS ID: ${printData.posId}")
            .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
            .setCharacterCode(DefaultPrinter.CHARCODE_PC437)
            .setNewLinesAfter(2)
            .build()
    )

    add(
        TextPrintable.Builder()
            .setText("APPROVED")
            .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALIGNMENT_CENTER)
            .setFontSize(DefaultPrinter.FONT_SIZE_LARGE)
            .setEmphasizedMode(DefaultPrinter.EMPHASIZED_MODE_BOLD)
            .setUnderlined(DefaultPrinter.UNDERLINED_MODE_OFF)
            .setNewLinesAfter(1)
            .build()
    )


    add(
        TextPrintable.Builder()
            .setText("Transaction: Withdrawal")
            .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
            .setCharacterCode(DefaultPrinter.CHARCODE_PC437)
            .setNewLinesAfter(1)
            .build()
    )

    add(RawPrintable.Builder(byteArrayOf(27, 100, 4)).build())
}
```

And this is the printed invoice:
[Printed invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM3q5.jpg)

I checked the official documents and the code seems right

Comment: The [Printooth repository](https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth) contains an example app that also does some alignment. Have you checked if the example app works?

Comment: Yes I checked and even with example app I have the same issues. I think there is a problem with printer compatibility

Comment: Maybe you can add a bit of context to your issue report in github, maybe add the same code and also the exact printer type. Let's hope the maintainer can help you with the issue